# Infinite loop when resizing images

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, infinite-loop, image-resizing

I am running my code to resize all images in a directory however the code goes on an infinite loop. The images are resized how I want I just can not figure out how to make it stop after one pass. Also I would like to specify the output to be a .jpg file type.

```
import os, sys
from PIL import Image
import glob as glob

MY_DIRECTORY = "C:\\Users\\rzara\\Desktop\\sample_skulls"
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(MY_DIRECTORY):
    for filename in files:
        for filename in glob.glob(MY_DIRECTORY+"/*.jpg"):
            size = 250, 250
            file_parts = os.path.splitext(filename)
            outfile = file_parts[0] + '_250x250' + file_parts[1]
            try:
                img = Image.open(filename)
                img = img.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
                img.save(outfile)
            except IOError as e:
                print("An exception occured '%s'" %e)
```

I tried changing the save line to:

```
img.save(outfile,'jpg')
```

but that gives and error of:

```
line 1983, in save 
save_handler = SAVE[format.upper()]
KeyError: 'JPG'
```

Comment: this is multiple things being asked. Your title asks about the infinite loop and then on your example you show a KeyError. Which is it?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to iterate over the `files` given by `walk`, _and_ iterate over the files given by `glob`. Try to do just one or the other.

Comment: It's easier to debug this without the try. It will look horrible but you must learn to debug from ugly squiggle lines that make no sense to a human for the most part. I'd suggest pulling it out of the try block, then come back after another test and you get a specific error. It could also be any of the three functions you are running inside the try block, so this will actually tell us exactly what line and in what file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems.

First, you are calling `walk` *and* `glob`, and iterating over the results of both. That means if your directory contains five files and all of them satisfy glob's pattern, you will iterate over five files five times for a total of twenty five times. You should only have one `for filename` loop.

Second, "jpg" does not appear to be a [supported PIL file format](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html). However, "JPEG" is. Try that instead. (Yes, I find it strange that `img.save("result.jpg")` understands that the result should be a jpeg, but `img.save("result", "jpg")` doesn't. Sometimes libraries are weird.)

All together, the result might look like:

```
import os, sys
from PIL import Image
import glob as glob

MY_DIRECTORY = "C:\\Users\\rzara\\Desktop\\sample_skulls"
for filename in glob.glob(MY_DIRECTORY+"/*.jpg"):
    size = 250, 250
    file_parts = os.path.splitext(filename)
    outfile = file_parts[0] + '_250x250' + file_parts[1]
    img = Image.open(filename)
    img = img.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(outfile, 'jpeg')
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the following 3 lines to the end of the program to look for any other errors that the try may be hitting?

```
    except Exception as message:
        print('general exception')
        print(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for filename in files:
    for filename in glob.glob(MY_DIRECTORY+"/*.jpg"):
```

You fetch a file name from `files`, but immediately replace it with a *sequence* of file names from a different source.  Although this is not, ipso facto, an infinite loop, it strongly suggests that you have a serious structure error.